# manually executing script on cygwin works but not remote

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to figure out what exactly an issue is, below is the step i am trying :

1. on Windows 2019, installed cygwin64, directly from cygwin terminal,  executing beloow  "configure" script works fine, below is the configure command :

```
 bash configure --with-freetype=bundled --with-tools-dir=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/ --with-boot-jdk=/cygdrive/c/jdk-10.0.2/ --with-jtreg=/cygdrive/c/jtreg-5.1-b01/ --with-version-pre=sncmid --with-version-build=$build --with-version-opt=
```

2. However when i automate using jenkins which will execute on windows slave node, it is failing with this below

```
configure: Found potential Boot JDK using configure arguments
configure: Potential Boot JDK found at /cygdrive/c/jdk-10.0.2/ is incorrect JDK version (Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8); ignoring
configure: (Your Boot JDK version must be one of: 10 11)
configure: error: The path given by --with-boot-jdk does not contain a valid Boot JDK

configure exiting with result code 1
```

Wondering why the difference between "direct execute on cygwin works fine" and "from jenkins job" where i called using "`c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l script.sh`" this `script.sh` executes configure script.

Invocation of the script

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l '%WORKSPACE%\script.sh' %BUILD_NUMBER% /cygdrive/c/openjdk11windows
```

content of script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $1 
build=$1 
source ~/.bash_profile 
source ~/.bashrc 
bash configure --with-freetype=bundled --with-tools-dir=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/ --with-boot-jdk=/cygdrive/c/jdk-10.0.2/ --with-jtreg=/cygdrive/c/jtreg-5.1-b01/ --with-version-pre=sncmid --with-version-build=$build --with-version-opt=
```

If any one has idea about this, please share.

Comment: content and location of the `script.sh` ?

Comment: @matzeri:
**
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l '%WORKSPACE%\script.sh' %BUILD_NUMBER% /cygdrive/c/openjdk11windows
**


content of `script.sh`:
**
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
build=$1

source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
 bash configure --with-freetype=bundled --with-tools-dir=/cygdrive/c/progra~2/micros~1/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/ --with-boot-jdk=/cygdrive/c/jdk-10.0.2/ --with-jtreg=/cygdrive/c/jtreg-5.1-b01/ --with-version-pre=sncmid --with-version-build=$build --with-version-opt= 
**

Comment: The additional info must go in the question. Please check if my edit was correct.

Comment: I have serious dobts that VC tools can work with Cygwin path style. Are you trying to build for Cygwin or for Windows ?

Comment: i am trying to build openjdk @matzeri